Pull Data From Multiple Sheets Based On Sheet Name
I have a an Excel Workbook with multiple sheets.  These sheets are organized as follows:
'Company1','Company1 News','Company1 Jobs','Company2','Company2 News','Company2 Jobs','Company3' ...
I need to pull data into a sheet titled "Opportunities" from only the sheets with "Jobs" in the sheet names using the criteria of having text in Column B of the " Jobs" sheets.
The number of Companies (Sheets) increase/decrease; therefore, I used 'BEGINNING' and 'DIVIDER' tabs at the beginning and end of the array of sheets.
The following formula works to pull the data I need from All Sheets; however, I need it filtered to only include data from the "... Jobs" sheets.
=FILTER(VSTACK(BEGINNING:DIVIDER!A13:M513),VSTACK(BEGINNING:DIVIDER!B13:B513)<>"","NO CURRENT OPPORTUNITIES")

I looked into different macros to try and sort by sheets, VLOOKUP, FILTER, etc.  But I can't seem to pull a solution together.

Please share sample data.

You can use notation like this:
=FILTER(VSTACK('*Jobs*'!A13:M513),VSTACK('*Jobs*'!B13:B513)<>"","NO CURRENT OPPORTUNITIES")

However, this formula is not stored in this form in the formula bar, but is immediately converted into a list of references, so if you add a new sheet it will not work. If you plan adding sheets you should have a text copy of this formula or short macro loading it to .Formula2 property of the cell.

Using the Formula property will only populate a single cell; the Formula2 property must be used instead.

@SpectralInstance  I do plan on adding sheets.  I apologize for not originally posting.
How would I write such a Macro?  It seems much more complicated than just inserting the formula, no?

@Progolfer79 Worksheets("Opportunities").Cells(2, 1).Formula2 = "=FILTER(VSTACK('*Jobs*'!A13:M513),VSTACK('*Jobs*'!B13:B513)<>"""",""NO CURRENT OPPORTUNITIES"")"

Adapted from the code here
Sub Filter_Jobs_Sheets()
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If InStr(1, sh.Name, "jobs", vbTextCompare) Then dict.Item(sh.Name) = sh.Evaluate("Filter(A13:M513, B13:B513 <> """", ""NO CURRENT OPPORTUNITIES"")")
    Next sh
    
    Dim it As Variant
    For Each it In dict.items
        Worksheets("Opportunities").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(it), UBound(it, 2)) = it
    Next it
End Sub

